# How to install Async CTP when i have My Documents shared from other disk

Tags: c#, asynchronous, installation

I try to install Async CTP and it says that installation was completed successfully, but nothing installs into "My Documents" and i cant find the samples. What can be done to see the samples with libraries and try them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have another machine you can install on at all?

My netbook didn't accept the CTP installation properly, but it *did* do enough magic to the C# compiler to make that part work. I then just copied AsyncCtpLibrary.dll from another machine where the installation *had* worked, and all was fine. If you want to copy the samples as well, I'm sure they'd work too.

If this turns out to be a common problem, I suggest we ask for permission to publish a zip file with the samples and library.

Here's a short program to let you see if you've got the C# compiler bits installed:

```
public class Test
{
    static async void Main() {}
}
```

That should fail with an error like this:

```
Test.cs(4,22): error CS0656: Missing compiler required member
        'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.VoidAsyncMethodBuilder.Create'
Test.cs(4,22): error CS1993: Cannot find Task-related types. Are you missing a
        reference to 'AsyncCtpLibrary.dll' ?
Test.cs(4,22): warning CS1998: This async method lacks 'await' operators and
        will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await
        non-blocking API calls, or 'await TaskEx.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work
        on a background thread
```

Comment: No, not another machine. Same machine, but other partition(i prefer to save my documents to not system partition). Thank you for the answer..Ill try to check the compiler, tho wanted the samples too, to see the completed solutions and tricks.

Comment: yeah, the bits are there, so the installer didn't install the samples and libraries. Thank you again..Hope microsoft will let the samples be downloaded separately.

Comment: My work machine has the My Documents folder shared from another disk, and my home machine only has Visual Studio Express. The Samples folder wasn't created on either! It would be nice to be able to try this out...

Comment: @Graham: Having spoken to the team, I don't think it's a problem of the "My Documents" location, but that the installer tries to do things to Visual Studio as part of the installation.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is to extract the contents of the setup program with Universal Extractor then run VS10-KB0000001.msp. It installs the samples, documentation, and patch.

Answer (score 1):

> > Here's a short program to let you see if you've got the C# compiler bits installed:
> >     Test.cs(4,22): error CS0656: Missing compiler required member        'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.VoidAsyncMethodBuilder.Create'

Thats exactly what I got a, after the CTP refresh, and MVC3 install. Tried removing MVC3 again and un/install the CTP, but the problem remains. Why would the install not correctly update the compiler?

Tnx

Comment: Removed that CTP :).. After that used Tasks a lot to gain experience in the way async programming will work in C#5. So i'll wait for all that goodies...